# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked

Tags: android, sqlite

I have done lots of operations with Sqlite database and now I am creating dynamically db file for different logged in user and the name of db file belongs to logged-in username.
and using database file according to their log-in.

I am getting **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** when I am trying to get new Instance of that db file. 
e.g.

```
   DatabaseHelper dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
   dbHelper.methodOfDatabase();  // Throwing Exception
```

> Here is my DatabaseHelper Class code snippet

```
 public static String DATABASE_NAME = "";

 public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String dbNmae) {
        super(context, dbNmae, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        DATABASE_NAME = dbNmae;
    }
```

> And here is my method to check or create new db file

```
 public String checkOrCreateDB(String dbName) {

        if (databaseFilesList.contains(dbName)) {
              DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME = dbName;
        } else {
              DatabaseHelper.getNewDatabase(activity, dbName).getWritableDatabase();
              DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME = dbName;
        }
        return DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
     }
```

> And finally this method to create new database file.

```
 public static DatabaseHelper getNewDatabase(Context context, String dbName) {
        if(mInstance != null)
        {
            mInstance.close();
        }
        mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context, dbName);
        return mInstance;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What's the value of `dbNmae` you're passing on to the `super` constructor?

Comment: Its combination of 3 strings like-  UserType, UserName and CurrentYear e.g. Other_John_2019

Comment: If it was an empty string then that would explain the behavior. Anyway, please post your stacktrace, too.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at java.lang.String.charAt (Native Method)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getDatabasePath (ContextImpl.java:852)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDatabasePath (ContextWrapper.java:341)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:371)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:341)
  at db.DatabaseHelper.getPartOneUploadStatus (DatabaseHelper.java:10274)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an empty string `""` to `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor. The code doesn't show exactly where the empty string comes from but that explains this crash.

[`getDatabaseLocked()`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java;l=371) gets invoked when you call to e.g. `getWritableDatabase()` and it passes the name to [`Context#getDatabasePath()`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java;l=859) that reads the first character without checking there is a first character at all.

Comment: Thanks laalto, it was exactly the same issue. the DB name string was blank which I supplied in constructor.